# Sharepoint dashboards interaction

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, development, business-intelligence, bi

On a SP BI solution there are two dashboards, both interactive. The wish is when someone click on a field in the left dashboard, an action is happening in the right dashboard, that is, sorting the field corresponding to the right field.

What could be the action to take, and how?

An illustration,
[image]